# Sencha touch 2.4.1 datepicker issue in Samsung galaxy s8 plus

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, extjs, senchatouch-2.4

We are facing one issue with sencha touch date picker. Our application is developed in Sencha touch 2.4.1 and working fine in all devices except in **Samsung s8 plus** where if we try to select December, it don't get selected.

If anyone faced similar kind of issue and able to fix it. Please help.

> Date-picker code:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    placeHolder: 'Date Of Birth',
    cls: [
        'myCustomField',
        'customDateField'
    ],
    dateFormat: 'd/m/Y',
    labelCls: 'dobLabel',
    itemId: 'DOB',
    value: {
        year: 1995,
        day: 1,
        month: 1
    },
    name: 'birthday',
    label: ' ',
    labelWidth: '15%',
    picker: {
        yearFrom: 1900,
        yearTo: 2020,
        slotOrder: ['day', 'month', 'year']
    }
}
```

> CSS

```
.myCustomField{
     font-family: KfontSemi1;
     font-size: 20px !important;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    /*margin: 0px 6px 0px 7px !important;
    /* it was commented previously, uncommented for text field in Vm write comments*/
     font-family: 'KfontSemi1', arial, san-serif !important;
}
 .myCustomField input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #cbcbcb !important;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
     font-size: 16px !important;
     font-family: KfontSemi1;
}
 .myCustomField .x-input-text::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #cbcbcb !important;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
     font-size: 16px !important;
     font-family: KfontSemi1;
}
 .customDateField .x-component-outer::after {
     -webkit-mask-image: none !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-image: url('../../resources/images/calender_icon.png') !important;
     height: 22px !important;
     width: 22px !important;
     background-size: 22px !important;
     background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
 .customDateField .x-field-select .x-component-outer::after {
     background: none;
}
 .dobLabel {
     background-image: url('../../resources/images/cake-icon.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: 30px !important;
     background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Some code will help us understand the problem

Comment: I am, able to resolve it. Ref: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253320-DatePicker-cannot-select-last-item-in-slot-Desktop-Chrome